# How to set the first row selected by default in ag grid (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

How to set the ag-grid first row selected by default in angular.

here's the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-xabqct?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I want the first row is selected by default when opening the application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a property to uniquely identify a record (eg. `id`) for this.

1. Provide this function in your template.

```html
[getRowNodeId]="_getRowNodeId"
```

```
_getRowNodeId(data) {
  return data.id;
}
```

2. Provide this `id` for each object of `rowData`
3. In `onGridReady`, call `gridApi`'s `getRowNode(id).selectThisNode(true)` to select the first record.

```
this.gridApi.getRowNode(1).selectThisNode(true);
```

Check this updated [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-angular-hello-world-gktnft?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for reference.

Comment: How'bout when you are selecting the other row it should be highlight

Comment: not getting what you're trying to explain. Could u elaborate?

Comment: Are you somehow supposed to know what the ID of he first row is?